# hive outputs map-reduce counter

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Since HQL (hive sql) uses map-reduce underneath, I wonder how can I output the job's counters info (to console or to a log file) such as the counter info a map-reduce job outputs by default when job finishes.

I use counters in my custom Hive UDTF to get debug info logged for example:

> context.getReporter().getCounter("MyCounter","Forward_Count").increment(1);

An example screen shot of the "counters info" i mentioned above:
[map-reduce counter example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKLJj.jpg)

Comment: Please put some more effort into wording, grammar and punctuation because it's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko Is it better now?